# Why did i get this error?

Tags: java

here's the code:

```
class Acount
{ int sum ; String owner ; //these seem to make sense 
    //a constructor or two 
    public Acount () 
    { this.sum = 0 ; this.owner = "John Doe" ; }

    public Acount (String name) 
    {this.sum = 0 ; this.owner = name ; } 

    public Acount (String name, int sum) 
    {this.sum = sum ; this.owner = name ; } 

    //prints an acount in the format "owner" "sum" 
    public static void printAcount (Acount Acount) 
    {System.out.print (Acount.owner) ; System.out.print (" ") ; System.out.println (Acount.sum) ; } 

    public static void main (String[]arg) 
    { 
        Acount Acount1 = new Acount ("david", 100) ; 
        System.out.println ("heres the first acount as it was created:") ; 
        printAcount (Acount1) ; 
        System.out.println ("now i changed one of its instance varaibles with a static method") ; 
        upOne (Acount1) ; 
        printAcount (Acount1) ; 
    } 

    public static Acount upOne (Acount Acount)
    { 
        Acount.sum = Acount.sum + 1 ; 
        return Acount ; 
    } 
}
```

here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Acount/java
```

What went wrong and why?

Comment: Unrelated, but names of class instances should not start with a capital letter.  The Java naming convention: "Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter."

Comment: it will still work though won't it?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one problem with the question is that the code is (besides an eyesore for Java conventions and spelling reasons) not relevant to the question.

Comment: I know "Why did I get this error, here is the code" is what most SO questions boil down to, but we tend to expect more context than that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you run the Java program in the command line, is it like this?

```
java Account.java
```

If yes, the remove the .java, because the `java` command takes a class name, not the file.
The correct command is:

```
java Account
```

Also, make sure you compiled the file properly.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the way you are calling your class from the commandline.  You shouldnt put the `.java` after your class name.  try:

```
java -classpath . Account
```

Answer (score 1):

That error represents an error in your command line. Try

```
 java Acount
```

Not java Acount.java